# Changing WhatsApp number without losing chat histories

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, chat-history

The SIM of my currently used WhatsApp number is not with me now. I want to change my WhatsApp number without losing some important chat histories. Is it possible to change the old WhatsApp number to a new one with some old specific chat histories intact, by verification only through the email ID associated with the previous WhatsApp number?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp makes it very simple to change your number. After changing your number, everything will stay the same. All your groups and chats will stay intact.

To change your number, open WhatsApp settings and press on *account* and then press in *change number*. Follow the simple steps to verify your new number.

That's all! All your groups and conversations will still be there.

---

Just make sure to let your contacts know that you changed your number. Otherwise they will not be able to reach you...